# How do I disable electric indent on RET but still keep other electric characters (e.g., ‘{’)?

Tags: emacs, indentation, emacs24, auto-indent, cc-mode

In Emacs 24.4, the default indentation behavior has been changed—new lines are now automatically indented.  From the [release notes](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/news/NEWS.24.4):

```
*** `electric-indent-mode' is now enabled by default.
Typing RET reindents the current line and indents the new line.
`C-j' inserts a newline but does not indent.  In some programming modes,
additional characters are electric (eg `{').
```

I prefer the old behavior, so I added

```
(electric-indent-mode 0)
```

to my `.emacs` file.  However, this disables all electric characters, which is not what I intended.

Is there any way to disable the new behavior while still having characters like ‘{’ or ‘:’ trigger an indentation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to remove `?\n` from `electric-indent-chars`.  You can do this globally with:

```
(setq electric-indent-chars (remq ?\n electric-indent-chars))
```

or only in a particular mode (e.g. C):

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq-local electric-indent-chars (remq ?\n electric-indent-chars))))
```

Answer (score 0):

By checking the documentation for `c-electric-brace`, I found that the behavior of electric characters is controlled by the buffer-local variable `c-electric-flag`.  It worked after I added the following lines to my `.emacs` file:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set 'c-electric-flag t)))

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set 'c-electric-flag t)))
```